# Scope of Product Owner responsibilities/authority in Agile process

Tags: scrum, process, agile

Inspired by: [What's the value to be realized in a 'team work agreement'?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187716/whats-the-value-to-be-realized-in-a-team-work-agreement)

I am mostly familiar/experienced with Agile in Software Development and Scrum. The question was regarding **a Product Owner pushing the team for a "Team Work Agreement"**. Specifically:

> She recently asked her team to create a 'team work agreement', which she claims is "standard practice in Agile shops."

For clarification, I interpret 'asked' as *requested*, not *suggested* e.g. during a Retrospective.

**Is it constructive for the Product Owner to contribute with the Team's process in this way?**

This seems to go against Agile Principles and Values. I have not seen a (functioning) implementation of Agile that allows such intervention.

**Clarification:** This question: [Product Owner complaining that he's not part of the team](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/174184/120142) and specifically [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/174199/120142) answer is relevant. My interpretation of the 'Team Work Agreement' is that it was an imposed demand, and not a suggestion. **Can such an <s>contribution</s> intervention be compatible with Agile?**

Comment: I think you're getting on a high horse here for no particular reason. The PO is as entitled as anyone else to suggest improvements to the process the team uses.

Comment: I apologise for the tone of the question - upon re-reading, it does sound like that. I interpreted the original question as the P.O. imposing/dictating process, which is different to their 'entitlement to suggest improvements' .

Comment: I have given the question a quick edit to soften the tone a bit

Comment: @motosubatsu thank you, and I think it helps. I have also updated the question for clarity.

Comment: It probably depends on which Agile god you pray to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the value to be realized in a 'team work agreement'?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187716/whats-the-value-to-be-realized-in-a-team-work-agreement)

Comment: This is a duplicate withe the linked question, which answers exactly the question "Is this normal Agile practice"‽

Comment: @DJClayworth - it is not. I am specifically asking if the Product Owner having such a role is constructive to Agile, or not - regardless of the specific request described in the linked question. I have not seen a (functioning) implementation of Agile that allows such intervention, and the reason I opened a separate question was because I considered it out-of-scope in the original.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Different companies do "Agile" in different ways, but that doesn't mean they all work.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments - I have been challenging my own thought process - but this question still bothers me. The product owner is a member of the team, and it is a no-brainer that the team should be recepting to *suggestions*, during both formal and informal opportunities. In the case of the original question, it felt to me like the PO was applying some non-agile authority in imposing a process, and I would find value in how a team should respond to such a demand, assuming they felt it as imposed and not produced organically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product Owner is a stakeholder in the development process as much as the developers, and so perfectly entitled to make suggestions. Even if they were not, a good agile team should be listening to anyone with a suggestion on how to make their process more effective.

The way in which a team works can affect the Product Owner's effectiveness very much. For example if the team works in such a way that their progress cannot be tracked or predicted then that is a problem, as it means the PO is unable to forecast the amount of work that will be completed by the team, either in the short term or long term. If something the team did made their estimates wildly inaccurate, or if they weren't recording the current state of stories in a transparent way, that would be a problem.

Product Owners also tend to be knowledgeable about product management and software processes. For a team to ignore a suggestion for improvement *solely because it comes from the product owner* would be extremely counterproductive. In my other answer I describe the benefits of Team Agreements. The team should listen to any suggestions and discuss, with reasons, whether a Team Agreement would benefit the organization as a whole - not just the developers, but also the other stakeholders.